# App crash problem after changing next Activity?

Tags: android, firebase

I'm developing a simple smart lock app with google sign in with firebase. After login to authentication activity, I tried to change activity to my main activity through "change to main activity" button. But it suddenly crash. Is there any solution for this problem?

In java:

```
    public void openMainActivity(View view) {
        Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

In layout:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_change"
        android:text="Servo Lock"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:onClick="openMainActivity"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_sign_out"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I expect that it can change from auth activity to main activity. But the app suddenly crash.

Comment: post your error log please. If not is impossible to know the cause.

Comment: post your log error

Comment: I only have this as error: https://i.imgur.com/1uNVwJR.jpg

Comment: you have a null pointer exception... Check you are getting the right object reference when you go into mainActivity

Comment: Where can I check this null pointer exception?

Comment: Usually is when using object without doing findViewById or something similar

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you registered Activity in Manifest file. If again app crash then shares an error log to find the exact problem.

Comment: I already register both Activity in Manifest file. This is the bug on my phone (I don't use emulator in android studio):
https://i.imgur.com/1uNVwJR.jpg